# Vue-jstree-how to edit Configuration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

[vue-jsTree Plugin](https://github.com/zdy1988/vue-jstree)

in this plugin in JSON they are using key `text` for populating the tree, 
how to change the key `text` to user defined key for populating,

in this JSON, they are using like

```
"text": "Same but with check boxes",
```

i want to use as :

```
'myLabel': "Same but with checkboxes",
```

how to do like this?

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t62NU.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [api doc](https://github.com/zdy1988/vue-jstree#api), you can change the value of text-field-name to 'myLabel'.